# Help finding a horror/sci Fi trilogy about bugs that go down people's throats as larvae and take over their bodies

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I don't remember the name or year or studio, but I'll give all the info I know.

The first one started off with lower class individuals at the DMV in I think New York, the main characters were random strangers who started talking to each other and noticed that others at the DMV weren't coming back out into the lobby, and then the main character got called back and went through a decontamination shower before going back to what looked like a human meat grinder, he survived and escaped, one of the other characters had a mail truck they escaped to and got away in. The main villain was a white woman, seductive 20s maybe. The larvae barely fit down people's throats and people were killed for food or turned bug, the bugs have taken over the police, politicians, etc. The main characters can't trust anyone and are limited by their low class status. Main character was a white guy, but the others were diverse.

In the sequel or 3rd movie (can't remember) the cold open starts with a flashback of astronauts being taken over by the bugs. One survives, a young white guy who isn't sure if he's a bug now or not, he tells the main characters that if they kill the queen, all the bugs die. They don't trust him, but they do the plan. They end up burning up the entire nest while the astronaut gets a larvae down his throat, they use a grenade in the nest and the nest is in a sewer/the subway station. The main characters barely make it out and in the end of the 3rd movie one larvae is showed to be still alive.

I think the trilogy was made by Sci-fi, and I found the full set in a Walmart $5 bin in probably 2012, so it wasn't a big hit. Please help me find the name of it, I loved the movies.

Comment: "made by Sci-fi". Do you mean [Syfy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syfy)?

Comment: @Laurel In 2012 (or earlier when this was made) it was Sci-Fi Channel; they hadn't rebranded yet.

Answer (score 11):

Might this be ***[Final Days of Planet Earth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478073/)*** (2006)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Days_of_Planet_Earth):

> *Final Days of Planet Earth* is a 2006 science fiction miniseries directed by Robert Lieberman and written by Roger Soffer. Starring Campbell Scott, Gil Bellows, and Daryl Hannah, the movie was produced by RHI Entertainment for the Hallmark Channel.

> **Three years ago, a team of astronaut miners completed a daring space expedition. They embarked on their journey home, but by the time the craft returned to Earth, their commander had gone mad—taking a terrible secret with him to a heavily guarded state asylum for the insane.** Today, archeologist Lloyd Walker and entomologist Marianne Winters are among a select group of people who are questioning a possible link between the tragic space mission, the mystery of the commander’s madness, and a series of bizarre disappearances and strange accidents in San Francisco. The answer arrives when they stumble upon an underground colony of insect-like creatures harvesting human bodies for survival.
>
> **Liz Quinlan, now an employee of the mayor’s office, knows all too well the secret of the aliens, given that she is their Earth Queen. The city's highest representatives are her consorts. With police and government officials taken over by aliens masquerading as humans,** Lloyd and Marianne realize they can trust no one, except William Phillips, the one man who knows the ultimate goal of the aliens. He also holds the mysterious key to their defeat—it's in his blood. He is the commander himself—the sole mission survivor being held as prisoner. Lloyd and Marianne must find him before he becomes a victim of an unearthly experiment.

As the Wikipedia page notes, it's a two-part miniseries rather than a movie trilogy, but each episode was feature length, it's about the right age, and made-for-TV, as you suggested.

The plot is also very similar to your description, with officials at San Francisco City Hall being used as hosts by alien larvae brought back from an expedition to the Moon, and an alien queen played by Daryl Hannah.

The protagonist of the series is subjected to a decontamination shower at one point, as shown at around the [0:41](https://youtu.be/Q1WBienb9Jc?t=41) mark in the trailer below.

Comment: From OP's description I was pretty sure this was it, even before reading your answer, so seconded.

Comment: YES! Thank you!

Comment: @Leviathan - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].